# Scrapy - Set TCP Connect Timeout

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website via Scrapy. However, the website is extremely slow at times and it takes almost 15-20 seconds to respond at first request in browser. Anyways, sometimes, when I try to crawl the website using Scrapy, I keep getting TCP Timeout error. Even though the website opens just fine on my browser. Here's the message:

```
2017-09-05 17:34:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.hosane.com/result/spec
ialList> (failed 16 times): TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party di
d not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to re
spond..
```

I have even overridden the `USER_AGENT` setting for testing.
I don't think `DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT` setting works in this case, since it defaults  to 180 seconds, and Scrapy doesn't even take 20-30 seconds before giving a TCP timeout error.

Any idea what is causing this issue? Is there a way to set TCP timeout in Scrapy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `TCP connection timed out` can happen before the Scrapy-specified `DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT` because the actual initial TCP connect timeout is defined by the OS, usually in terms of TCP `SYN` packet retransmissions.

By default on my Linux box, I have 6 retransmissions:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries
6
```

which, in practice, for Scrapy too, means `0 + 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 (+64) = 127 seconds` before receiveing a `twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.` from Twisted. (That's the initial trial, then exponential backoff between each retry and not receiving a reply after the 6th retry.)

If I set `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries` to 8 for example, I can verify that I receive this instead:

```
User timeout caused connection failure: Getting http://www.hosane.com/result/specialList took longer than 180.0 seconds.
```

That's because `0+1+2+4+8+16+32+64+128(+256) > 180`.

`10060: A connection attempt failed...` seems to be a Windows socket error code. If you want to change the TCP connection timeout to something at least the `DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT`, you'll need to change the TCP `SYN` retry count. (I don't know how to do it on your system, but Google is your friend.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems like the correct answer. I will get back to you after trying it out! :)

Comment: Note that for me, even with a very high timeout, that website did not respond every time, and most often did not.

Comment: But I'm able to access the website in my browser... Then why is it behaving differently with Scrapy, even with the user agent...

Comment: I can observe that the TCP connection is not even establishing most of the time. This happens before any User Agent string is sent as part of the HTTP request. Then I guess you'll need to compare what Scrapy/Twisted and your browser do at the TCP level (I use Wireshark for this.)

Comment: So I had another look, and it looks like the website is served at 2 IP addresses: 139.224.19.196 and 61.129.78.163. The former responds often (all the time?) and the other very rarely (never?). You could use the working address instead of the domain name, or you could force a DNS entry for www.hosane.com to point to 139.224.19.196.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to be the problem, but accessing that IP address from my browser gives me a 403. But I'll look into it. Thanks a lot for all of that information. It's really helpful