# What does "TypeError: to_bytes must receive a str or bytes object, got NoneType" mean?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am locked because of:

```
TypeError: to_bytes must receive a str or bytes object, got NoneType.
```

Here is my script:

```
# lbc_ads_to_scrap.py

import scrapy


class LbcAdsToScrapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lbc_ads_to_scrap'
    allowed_domains = ['aia-immobilier.fr']
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            'https://aia-immobilier.fr/fr/',
            meta={
                'proxy':'85.135.67.143'
            }

        )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'balise_h1': response.xpath('//h1')
        }
```

Here is my error:

```
     2024-01-04 17:31:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://aia-immobilier.fr/fr/>
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1656,     in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 489, in     throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py",   line 49, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 67, in   mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 75, in download_request
    return handler.download_request(request, spider)
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-  packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 65, in download_request
    return agent.download_request(request)
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 327, in download_request
    agent = self._get_agent(request, timeout)
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site- packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 279, in _get_agent
    proxyScheme, proxyNetloc, proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyParams = _parse(proxy)
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\webclient.py", line 40, in _parse
    return _parsed_url_args(parsed)
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\webclient.py", line 21, in _parsed_url_args
    host = to_bytes(parsed.hostname, encoding="ascii")
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 107, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('to_bytes must receive a str or bytes '
    TypeError: to_bytes must receive a str or bytes object, got NoneType
```

Where is my error. I checked my URL and it looks good. My proxy too.

Comment: meta={"proxy": "http://proxy_address:port"} , is port missing ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @pippo1980 yes but it still does not work. Only when I put “proxy “. I dont know why?!

Comment: ```meta={"proxy": "http://192.168.1.1:8050"})```

Comment: thank you but now  I receive this error: DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://aia-immobilier.fr/fr/> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 10060: Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu..

Comment: no idea, connections time out , not an expert could be thousand of stuff, check with other proxies it could be that it doesnt serves pages to known or in_some_way detected proxies , no idea. Does it work without using a proxy ? or gives the same timed out connection error ???  ask another question on look around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055295/scrapy-set-tcp-connect-timeout

Comment: This new question has nothing to do with your previous one, so you should open a new question.